# Must I wait for Alamofire to finish post request or is it all asynchronous

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I wonder how Alamofire run asynchronous?

When a user taps a button in my app this gets fired:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "www.someaddress", parameters: parameters, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON() { response in
                //Do nothing..
        }
```

Is the user still able to go back to the previous VC or must I wait for the Alamofire Post request to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to care about that, Alamofire runs all request `asynchronous`.

Check out the docu here:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md

> Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. Asynchronous
>   programming may be a source of frustration to programmers unfamiliar
>   with the concept, but there are very good reasons for doing it this
>   way.

And all requests still run automatically on an background-thread too. So you dont need to wait till the request is finished (No UI Interaction will be blocked)